# jQuery - animation doesn't work with z-index

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, z-index

There are two sliders I want to animate on mouse hover.
This works fine when I don't give the slides a z-index to hide them behind the wrapper.
But when I do the animation doesn't work anymore.

Here is what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/dW85E/3/

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: It only doesn't work when the `z-index` is a negative number. Otherwise it's fine ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dW85E/4/).)

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that it does work if you give the wrapper an absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/dW85E/5/